# rotating along directional vector producing unexpected result

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, vector

This is the scene at hand:
I applied three array modifiers, applied them and then merged vertices by distance.
I would like to instance the edges as cylinders so to speak, therefore I used a *Mesh to Points* node set to "Edges", which is plugged into *Instance on Points* node, with a cylinder primitive as instance.

In order to align the cylinders with the direction of the edges I use the *Edge VerticesE node and subtract them to get the directional vector from one vertex of an edge to the other. I then want to align the Z axis of the cylinders with their respective directional vector.

The idea is the following: Let's take the edge between one vertex and one that is above it: $(0,0,2)$ difference. The angle between $(0,0,1)$ and the directional vector is $0$ therefore it should point up.

If the difference was $(0,2,0)$ the cylinder should be rotated $90$ degrees to match it with the local z axis.

(because the cubes were of size $2$: Vertices had the difference of $2$).

In the second image I calculate the angle between the $(0,0,1)$ vector and the directional vector manually. The reason I chose $(0,0,1)$ is because that is the cylinders current Z axis. I basically emulate *Align Euler to Vector* and I suppose that worked because I get multiples of the same value down to its thousands decimal.

I dont understand why the values produced are multiples of $1.571$. I suppose since these aren't angles that the rotation is for that reason unaffected.

Does anyone know what is causing this issue?

[image: node setup]

[image: debugging attempt]

Comment: used wireframe and geometrynodes in combination.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is because when the edges are converted to points, they don't have "edge vertices" anymore (as they are not "edges").

To fix this, you want to capture the rotation ('Capture Attribute' node set to *Edge* and *Vector*) before converting the edges to points, and use that as the rotation.

Side note: The vector does not need to be normalized as the 'Align Euler to Vector' node does this.